# Using CSS for solid color background across/between table cells

Tags: html, css

Consider the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/EMbtq/):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Stack</td>
        <td>Overflow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 40px 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
tr:first-child {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I would like the background color on the first row to be between the cells also.

How could I do this ?

Comment: ngh... don't use tables for non-tabular data

Comment: don't really get the question!plez specify!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible when using `border-spacing`, but you could try using individual cell padding instead...

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
tr:first-child td {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
td {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

[Live demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/FMpCs/) available here

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry but according to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layers) (the last paragraph of section 17.5.1), the background between the cells when you use "border-collapse: separate" is the background of the table element.